# Class Cast Exception in while mocking bean

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testng

I am trying to create test cases in my application using powermock and TestNG. This is a web application and spring context xml is loaded through web.xml. I want to mock the spring context xml with my own test xml and access beans from there.

**ContextLoader Code**

```
 public class AppContextLoader implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private static ApplicationContext context;

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
      this.context = context;
  }

  public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
      return context.getBean(beanName);
  }
}
```

I am trying to access a bean later in my code like below

```
    XMLConverter converter = (XMLConverter) AppContextLoader.getBean("XMLConverter");
```

Below is my Test Code

```
@PrepareForTest(AppContextLoader.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.xml.*","org.xml.*","org.w3c.dom.*"})
public class ImplTest {

Impl impl;
ApplicationContext context;

   @ObjectFactory
   /**
    * Configure TestNG to use the PowerMock object factory.
    */
   public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
      return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
   }

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception {
     impl = new Impl();
     context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Test_config.xml");

}

@Test
public void execute() {

    try {
            PowerMock.mockStatic(AppContextLoader.class);
            expect(AppContextLoader.getBean("XMLConverter")).andReturn(context.getBean("XMLConverter"));
            PowerMock.replay(AppContextLoader.class);

            actualResponse = impl.execute(request, "");
            //PowerMock.verify(AppContextLoader.class);

            Assert.assertEquals("", actualResponse);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

When I am executing this code I am getting below error:

**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.bean.XMLConverter cannot be cast to com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.bean.XMLConverter**

I am new to unit testing, and not sure what is causing this issue where same class are not able to cast each other. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is that "EnvironmentBean"? What are you actually trying to achieve? To inject a mocked bean into Spring application context? If I understand your intention then maybe I can suggest easier ways to achieve the desired result.

Comment: there is a small typo, it should be XMLConverter, not EnvironmentBean what I am trying to load at test,corrected the same. Yes I want to use a mocked bean

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496711/adding-a-pre-constructed-bean-to-a-spring-application-context/2403276#2403276. In case of questions, ask.

Comment: The original issue is resolved after extnding the test class to PowerMockTestCase. The issue was becasue multiple classloader was involving the classes. Thanks for the approach